# Horizontal Lines on Second Monitor (Same Refresh on Both)

Tags: display

I have a secondary monitor, and it is a 19" while the main is 23", and they are both set at 60Hz refresh rate. I've noticed that when I am running certain programs, primarily full screen games or high memory applications (Unreal 4 Editor, as an example), I'll get white, upward scrolling horizontal lines on the second monitor.

The lines can be on the desktop, a browser window, or a full screen video, but the lines are about the same. I also get the lines in the second monitor (and not the main) if I have one of these programs running in the second monitor (if I drag the Unreal Editor to the second screen and have it in focus, for example).

Here is a picture I took of the problem while I had something running on the main and a youtube video going on the second:

[image]

Any advice or things to try? Thanks!

The monitors are both running off one GPU: an NVIDIA GTX 970. The main is connected DVI on the monitor side, running to HDMI on the GPU. The second monitor is running VGA on the monitor side, to a DVI adapter on the GPU. They are about 7 inches apart (edge to edge).

Comment: How close together are the monitors?

Comment: Psycogeek - Added the connections to the edit at the end.
SamB - About 7 inches apart.

Comment: It is possible that "better" cables for the analog (VGA) would reduce it, ones with ferrite beads even (although just proper shielded ones should be enough).

Comment: Interesting. I might have to try that. How does that affect the second monitor only when something process heavy is active on the main monitor?

Comment: How does that one monitor get effected?  some part of the paths to that monitor are analog, and with analog you are more likely to get issues exactally like this. with all digital paths things either work or they do not (for the most part) .  With analog itself the quality (sort of) had to be maintanted the whole way.

Comment: I'll try switching out my cables with higher quality ones, but to clarify, it is running through an adapter, not a converter box.

Comment: Ok removed that comment. Your adapting the VGA that exists on a DVI-I port on the video card itself?

Comment: It's one of those little VGA-DVI adapters. Like this: http://images.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/23971.jpg

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that this could be caused by a few different things.

1:  As the comments have mentioned, swapping out cables is the easiest step and could defintely fix the issue.  If you don't have extra cables, try just swapping which monitors use which cables, does the problem persist?

2:  Interference from some other source could be causing the signal degredation.  Make sure the signal cables are separated from any large power cables, and other sources of interference.

3:  Play around with the settings, try a different refresh rate, resolution, etc.  It might shed some light on the problem or maybe even solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same issues here using a HDMI and VGA same size monitors.

The issue here is that while each monitor is reporting @60FPS they are not actually refreshing each screen at the same rate..

(i.e the hdmi is 60.000 while the dvi is 59.999) this causes frame tearing/solid scrolling small black lines/transparent white bars/flickering).

a solution is to play with your scaling options to decrease the monitor sizes which prevents your DVI screen from infact having a line of pixel in on your HDMI that is infact ment for your DVI or VGA monitors.

another solution is to decrease the resolution of your VGA or DVI monitor incrementally. as it could also be the result of your gpu not being able to handle the load. (remember that every image you see is presented 60 times per second x2)

lastly your hdmi/dvi/vga cords or sockets could have dust thats not easily visible unplugging the cords from the sockets and blowing on the sockets and cords might also help.

goodluck :D